# How to send ASCII codes stream from an ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I developed an ASP.NET MVC application in C# that sends some commands to a device (for the case, it does not matter what device is).

From a controller, I am using this code to return the "OK" response:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetRequest(string SN, string INFO)
{
    string response = "OK";
        
    return Content(response), "text/plain");
}
```

When I analyze the HTTP protocol using Wireshark, I see this:

[image]

That looks OK, however, when I see the same, but using a supplier's web application (developed in Java), the same OK is returned, but it is seen in a different way. Maybe they are sending a bytes stream.

[image]

Notice that Wireshark shows a data stream 4F 4B. Which are ASCII codes of "OK".

Am I right that the other application is returning the "OK" word as a byte stream? To get the same in my ASP.NET MVC application, should I use `FileResult`?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Neither of you are working in ASCII, it is UTF-8 in both cases (which for a string like `"OK"` is the same bytes).  It's likely the different because it's a different web server.  The Java version has specified a UTF-8 content-encoding and it doesn't look like the C# version has that as a header.  Do they both work?  By the way, does your code compile?  My eyeball compiler is issuing an error on this: `return Content(response), "text/plain");`

Comment: @Flydog57... yes... it compiles. the actual code is `return Content(response, "text/plain");`. I don't know why the parenthesis was misplaced. Maybe when I removed some irrelevant code from the body I made that mistake. Both code works, Java version and mine version. The fact is that I think Java version is sending data that way for security reasons so I am trying to achieve the same. I am wondering why, in both, content type is text/plain, however, in Java version I need to decode the data first using a Wireshark option in order to see that readable.

Comment: There's no more "security" in one or the other. Try specifying the content encoding in a header

Comment: @Flydog57 Is it possible to completely customize the HTTP header sent to the client? Even when my app works, the return code from the device is different from the the code returned to the Java app. In both cases the command is exactly the same, so my only guess is about the header since this is not a browser, but a device. When returning `ContentResult` from the controller, some HTTP header items are added automatically. Is it possible to change that behaviour and send exactly the same HTTP headers the Java application does? Or maybe I should post a new question about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http client's are generally very forgiving of invalid header values.
`Content-Encoding: UTF-8` isn't a supported value. This header is supposed to indicate if the payload has been compressed. And which compression method has been used.

Since the header is present, Wireshark logs how it tries to decompress the payload. But can't because it isn't actually compressed. So it just displays the raw bytes in hexadecimal, since that is ultimately what Wireshark is for.